# Is there a trick to drawing cubic equation graphs?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

This year I started drawing out cubic graphs on graph paper...My teacher have been giving a ton of practices.However,I find that it is very difficult to connect the points of the graph,especially the curves...
So,is there a trick to drawing out on graph paper easily?
Oh,is the french curve or curve ruler easier to draw cubic graphs?

Comment: can you give an example please?

Comment: y=-x^3 +4x^2 -3 for -1.5<x<4
This was one of those that I had trouble connecting the points...
Should I use differentiation such that I find the turning points to make it easier?

Comment: Of course that would help..

Comment: But with more points,doesn't it mean that connecting them all would be tougher?Sorry,its just that drawing cubic graphs can take me sometimes 30 minutes or so because the I can't bend the curve ruler such that it fits the point...

Comment: Yes, you can buy a french curve, they are good for making pretty curves of different curvature.  But the aesthetics of your cubic curves are ultimately less important than having the shape approximately right.  i.e. Identifying where is the curve upward sloping and where is it downward sloping.

Comment: I got the shape,it's just that the the part for connecting the points and the smoothness of the curve...

Answer (score 1):

It's better to locate the point of inflection first:

Say for a graph of $f(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$,

$$f''\left( -\frac{b}{3a} \right)=0$$

The graph has a rotation symmetry about the point of inflection namely
$$\left( -\frac{b}{3a}, d-\frac{bc}{3a}+\frac{2b^3}{27a^2} \right)$$

Comment: Can you explain whats the formula for?I have never seen that before...I thought we can use differentiation for point of inflection?Sorry to trouble you.

Comment: $f''(x)=6ax+2b \implies f''(-\frac{b}{3a})=0$ and $d-\frac{bc}{3a}+\frac{2b^3}{27a^2}=f(-\frac{b}{3a})$

Comment: Wow,that awesome!!!But does f(x) only have one point of inflection?Since its a cubic graph,it should have 2 right?It changes direction twice right?

Comment: **One**  inflection point only.  $y=f(x)$ may have one local maximum and one local minimum coz $f'(x)$ is quadratic.

Comment: So,how about graphs of equations higher than to the power of 3,do they have more than one inflection points?If not,what type of functions have more than one inflection points?

Comment: It needs higher derivatives test:  If $f(x)$ is $k$ times continuously differentiable in a certain neighbourhood of a point $x$ with $k$ odd and $k\geq 3$, while $f^{(n)}(x_0)=0$ for $n=2,...,k-1$ and $f^{(k)}(x_0)\neq 0$ then $f(x)$ has a point of inflection at $x_0$.

Comment: wow!Thanks for the help!